# How to select items in app and updating the state in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to build a simple app like in **picture attached** with react js, I just cannot find the right idea of:

How to "select" photos(or item) in an application and have the **"cart"-like** component appear at the bottom when at least one photo/item is selected(and close and deselect all already selected photo/items) and expand the **cart-like** component at the bottom when clicked to show what's been already selected.

What is the best approach to this?
P.S I'm new to react with a big idea in mind xD

[app's view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9Iq9.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question definitely needs more information, but I will try to point you in the right direction. There are hundred of ways to create the UI/functionality you are describing but here is a very generic overview;

The "items" (Img1-6) looks like a grid of `ShopItem` components, possibly in a CSS Grid / flexbox. Each ShopItem would probably make use of an `onClick` method to "do something" when it is clicked - this may involve updating a state (using the useState react hook) somewhere which tells you if a ShopItem is checked or not. It could also potentially use a callback method to do something in the parent when the items are checked.
I imagine that each ShopItem may own its own "checked" state or may update a global state (Such as Zustand or Redux) or a Context (React) when it is toggled on and off. The checked state of a ShopItem would also inform the UI of the component.
The "cart-like" component could be looking at the global state/context/callback from the item component, and could change based on its value and how many checked items there are. (Eg/ `checkedItems !== 0 ? show : don't show`)

This is just one way in which this UI can be built, if you would like a more specific solution, please edit your question to include code snippets and what you've already tried.